# Конструктор SQL запросов

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть ли какой-нибудь конструктор SQL запросов? А то я в этих LEFT JOIN путаюсь)

ps: Как правильно MySQL-запрос, или SQL-запрос?

Обновление:

```
$sql  = "SELECT c.custom_value,b.product_name,a.virtuemart_product_id,b.slug FROM s2gsu_virtuemart_products a ";
$sql .= "LEFT JOIN s2gsu_virtuemart_products_ru_ru b ON b.virtuemart_product_id=a.virtuemart_product_id ";
$sql .= "LEFT JOIN s2gsu_virtuemart_product_customfields c ON c.virtuemart_product_id=b.virtuemart_product_id ";
$sql .= "WHERE c.virtuemart_custom_id=17 ORDER BY c.custom_value ASC LIMIT 0,15";
```

Зацените, всё ли правильно в запросе, LEFT JOIN - чудо, без него бы не сладко в такой ситуации мне пришлось бы)) Научился ему на этом чудесном форуме, благодаря пользователю **draev** , спасибо ему)

Comment: Конструктор удобно использовать на начальном этапе, а потом он только ограничивает возможности языка.

Самый, на мой взгляд, правильный вариант - выработать для себя удобный и читабельный вариант оформления запросов. Если весь запрос в одну строку и маленькими буквами, то кто-угодно запутается.

Comment: Вот запрос, который я поленился сначала сделать и создал эту тему) Но делать оказалось нечего и создал его сам: (добавил в свой пост), оцени пож-та, есть недостатки какие-то?

Comment: Для визуального восприятия лучше будет что-то типа:


    SELECT
        c.custom_value, b.product_name, a.virtuemart_product_id, b.slug
    FROM
        s2gsu_virtuemart_products AS a 
    LEFT JOIN s2gsu_virtuemart_products_ru_ru AS b
        ON b.virtuemart_product_id = a.virtuemart_product_id 
    LEFT JOIN s2gsu_virtuemart_product_customfields AS c
        ON c.virtuemart_product_id = b.virtuemart_product_id
    WHERE
        c.virtuemart_custom_id = 17
    ORDER BY c.custom_value ASC
    LIMIT 0, 15

или любой другой вариант верстки отступами. Каждый выбирает для себя сам.

Comment: спасибо, учту)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, к примеру, хороший скрипт `phpmyadmin`. Там можно практически все запроси или все сделать через конструктор. Правильно говорить SQL-запрос.

Comment: Спасибо, а где это в phpmyadmin? В "Окно запроса"?

Comment: Там вроде так и называется "SQL"

Comment: Не больно много удобоств предоставляет) Только название таблиц вставляет и всё)

Comment: Если вам надо сделать запрос select - тогда заходите вкладку "Поиск"  
инсерт - "вставка"
Обновление там в таблицы